# Where does signing/decrypting take place on a YubiKey 4/5 PIV private key?

Tags: public-key, cryptographic-hardware

I have a YubiKey 4 and want to use it to store a private key that should never enter a computer system's memory. After importing the key to the device I understand it never leaves it.  Do the signing/decryption operations that take place for plain text using the private key happen on the device's hardware? Also, if this does happen on hardware, then can it be used like an HSM if proper compliance does not require that it generate the key on the device?

Comment: I can't believe I made that many mistakes in one paragraph!! Thanks for the suggested edits. I rewrote the question a couple of times so the grammatical mistakes were due to a lack of time on my part. Thanks. Hope you don't catch any more errrors. =)

Comment: Signing is on device. Decryption is mixed, since hybrid encryption is the default. The ciphertext is encrypted symmetrically, this symmetric key is encrypted with the asymmetric key. So the device decrypts the symmetric key, which would then typically be given to the host computer so it can decrypt the full message.

Comment: What do you mean by decryption is mixed? Where is that documented? Where is this symmetric key stored? Is the symmetric key stored in the Microsoft cryptographic provider and is that encrypted by the private key as you stated? If what I am saying in my questions is all true and I understand correctly then the answer is that the decryption is happening on the OS and not the YubiKey. Is this symmetric key accessible if a person were to compromise the system and obtain root privileges so that they can decrypt further messages. I understand the concept but not the implementation with Microsoft.

Comment: To further clarify that symmetric key would at some point be in memory and what are the implications for other cipher text if the symmetric key were to be compromised.

Comment: each message gets a unique secret symmetric key, only used for that message. The symmetric key is encrypted to the public key, sent along with the message ciphertext. The Yubikey applet decrypts the symmetric key with the private key, sends the symmetric key to the OS. The OS decrypts the full message.

Comment: No other messages can be decrypted with that symmetric key. The key only protects that message, and the OS is getting full access to that message plaintext either way.

Comment: Where is this documented? I would love to learn more about this and other aspects. I could not find this information on their website.

Comment: Forgot to mention is that happening within the Microsoft Cryptographic provider when using Windows. You mentioned YubiKey applet. I am not using the applet or any YubiKey software. I used c# code which uses the Microsoft API and have actually used the key as if it is stored locally (of course it wasn't exportable because it resides in the hardware key). In other words is the process your mentioning taking place when utilizing the Microsoft crypto API when accessing the certificate from the YubiKey. Sorry for all the comments but it is still unclear how this works with the Windows API calls.

Comment: NIST standard for PIV answers this. Will post an actual answer here, need the space and it's an official source (yubikey mostly follows the spec)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the official specifications, published by NIST;

https://csrc.nist.gov/publications/detail/sp/800-73/4/final

NIST  Special  Publication  800-73-4 Interfaces  for  Personal  Identity Verification  –  Part  1:  PIV  Card Application Namespace,  Data Model  and  Representation

> A.5 Key  Establishment  Schemes  with  the PIV  Key  Management  Key
>
> FIPS  201  specifies a public key pair  and associated  X.509  Certificate for  Key Management. The  key management  key  (KMK)  is further  defined  in  SP  800-78, which  defines two  distinct  key establishment schemes for  the KMK:
>
> A.5.1.1  RSA  Key  Transport  with the PIV  KMK
>
> As specified  in  SP  800-78,  the on-card private KMK can  be an  RSA transport  key that complies  with [PKCS1].  In  the scenario  described  above,  a sender  encrypts a symmetric key  with  the KMK’s  public RSA transport key.  The  role  of  the  on-card  KMK private RSA transport  key  is to  decrypt  the sender’s symmetric  key on  behalf  of  the  cardholder  and provide  it  to the  client  application  cryptographic  module

The client application cryptographic module would typically mean the software on the computer that you connected the card to. It means that RSA operations happens on the card, but the computer will then decrypt the full message. It's designed this way to not make the card a bottleneck for large messages.

The Yubikey mostly follows the official spec for these protocols.

Comment: If I were to use the RSA mechanism without treating the card as a PIV but rather a secure store for the private key then technically it is feasible to have RSA operations be performed on the card. I have actually accomplished this in C# utilizing the Windows crypto API. Basically I am trying to produce a makeshift cheap version of HSM for the RSA only operations. I was able to also encrypt with the private key as well if my memory serves me well. I will look at the code again but based on the above statement it seems that you can use it for decrypting only.  Can one sign with the private key.

Comment: I don't remember if I just did decrypt on the card utilizing the certificate. I might have done the opposite but do you think that was possible? I need to find the code or rewrite it. I wanted these signing mechanisms to allow my end users to be able to securely sign things without compromising their private keys even myself on the client end.

Comment: Thanks for your effort I really appreciate you finding those specs relating to the YubiKey.

Comment: @samman yes, you can sign. That's covered elsewhere in the documents